# Swift: Import .csv as a string

Tags: xcode, swift, csv, import

I am using Swift to import a **.csv** file stored in the project. However, I always get the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I tried doing the same thing but converted it to a **.txt** file, and that failed also. However, if I just copy and paste the contents directly into a new **.txt** file, it works. I am just trying to turn this into a string so that I can work with it later.

```
let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SL", ofType:"csv")
var text = String(contentsOfFile: file!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
var rawStudents = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error means? That should always be your first goal. Do you know what an Optional is? Do you know what unwrapping an optional is? Do you know what nil is? Do you know what happens when you try unwrapping a nil optional?

Comment: Could you add a diff of the original file and that one that works?

Comment: csv means comma separated values. you should use componentsSeparatedByString(",")

Comment: Make sure when adding your csv file to your project to select the option copy to project if needed.

Comment: Later down I separate it based on commas. However, the information I was given was formatted poorly, so that was the first step of making any sense of it. The problem is just converting it to a string, which I have no experience with for Swift

Comment: Add if let to unwrap all optional values or use "??" Nil coalescing operator to handle it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure after dragging your csv file to your project to select the option copy to project if needed. You should always use if let to safely unwrap your optionals.

```
var error:NSError?
if let fileUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SL", withExtension:"csv") {
    if let text = String(contentsOfURL: fileUrl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
        let rawStudents = text.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    } else {
        println("error reading file")
        if let error = error {
            println(error.description)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to be a step closer. It seems the file loads, but doesn't get past the second if statement.

Comment: I have edited the answer why don't you try creating a new csv file, add it to your project as I said and check the error message

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=*{NSFilePath=/Users/*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A1762F92-945B-4945-866C-614B3EF6E18F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0138C3EB-343B-4428-9B34-69E13E9EADC5/St.app/SL.csv, NSStringEncoding=4}

Comment: That's probably an invalid csv file

Comment: Make sure it is a utf8 text file

Comment: Yep, it seems the csv file is broken. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After `let file=NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SL", ofType:"csv")` check if the file constant is nil or not, in the next line you are force unwrapping a potential nil which is a very bad idea.
The problem might be that the file is not located in the bundle.

Comment: The file is in the bundle.